# How does .NET allow API exploration of compiled DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, api, dll

How does .NET allow API exploration of compiled DLLs?

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed, it's related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507743/whats-the-rationale-behind-headers/1507755#1507755

Comment: Closing? How is this "Not a Real Question?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the DLL contains *metadata* about all the types, methods etc. Even the actual code is in IL rather than native code.

Basically a .NET binary is still at a higher level than a native binary, and contains a lot more information about what's in there. That's what allows Reflection to work.

Comment: So, is it accurate to say that C# gets compiled then? I'm asking because if I understand what you're saying, the IL then gets interpreted, right?

Comment: If i understand it correctly, IL is JIT compiled to the proper machine code as necessary.

Comment: Actually, both are true. On almost all .NET implementations, it is JIT compiled. But on "Micro Framework" it is interpreted. You aren't hugely likely to see Micro Framework much ;-p

Comment: Mono also has a bytecode interpreter, and IIRC can be forced to use it via command line switches.

Comment: A "mixed" assembly can contain both managed and unmanaged code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is what you are asking about, but I can only recommend the free tool [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm) that lets you explore any compiled .NET assembly.

These days, I use it much more than I use even the published MSDN documentation, because it's much faster to navigate around in, and more informative to boot.

Comment: Not really what he's asking, but nice try anyway.

Comment: I don't think it was apparent just what he was asking about, which was also why I qualified my answer by "I'm not sure if that is what you are asking about".

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

A DLL contains a list of functions exported, but these can be simply assigned a number, a name, or they can be assigned a [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) C++ name. The latter can give some insight in the function's parameters, but data structures, calling conventions and other required attributes are generally not documented.

If it's a COM DLL, there's a possibility that it contains a Type Library as a resource, but this is not guaranteed. In that case, .NET can import the library quite automatically.

A Type Library can also be included in a non-COM DLL, but this is not a widespread practice.

If you have a compiled DLL designed to be called from a non-COM, non-managed environment, you'll need to translate the header files that should be included with the DLL.

Comment: I believe the question is specific to .NET, so the C++/COM side - while interesting and accurate - doesn't really apply.

Comment: This question is a response to my comment about another question regarding headers, so no, I don't think it's specific to .NET DLL's.

Answer (score -1):

One Word: Reflector

Comment: Are you saying that Reflector will not provide exploration of metadata?